# whats the purpose of having infinite for loop in following code

Tags: java

Can somebody explain ....This is the official java AtomicBoolean getAndSet method's definition

```
public final boolean getAndSet(boolean newValue) {
        for (;;) {
            boolean current = get();
            if (compareAndSet(current, newValue))
                return current;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8, the [sourcecode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.java#AtomicBoolean.getAndSet%28boolean%29) has been slightly restructured, making it easier to understand:

```
public final boolean getAndSet(boolean newValue) {
    boolean prev;
    do {
        prev = get();
    } while (!compareAndSet(prev, newValue));
    return prev;
}
```

As you can see, [compareAndSet](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.java#AtomicBoolean.compareAndSet%28boolean%2Cboolean%29), which returns a boolean, which comes from the native function [Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/misc/Unsafe.java#Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt%28java.lang.Object%2Clong%2Cint%2Cint%29), might fail. In that case, the operation is simply repeated.

According to the documentation of [Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/misc/Unsafe.java#Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt%28java.lang.Object%2Clong%2Cint%2Cint%29),

```
Atomically update Java variable to x if it is currently holding expected.  
Returns:  
    true if successful
```

the function will fail if the value of the `AtomicBoolean` has been changed between calling `get()` and some point in [Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/misc/Unsafe.java#Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt%28java.lang.Object%2Clong%2Cint%2Cint%29). This usually shouldn't be the case, but when it happens, it will poll the current value once again and hope the same thing doesn't repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.If somehow compareAndSet does not written true and prev and newValue(because its a counter or something whose value does not repeat) will never matched. Is there a specific reason for using for loop? should not there be some exception raised or other exiting strategy?

Comment: @bharat9848: I don't think so, as the most common case where `compareAndSet` might fail is a data race, and in such a case there is a reasonably high chance that it will work in the next iteration. So, in favor of simplicity on the callers side, it makes sense not to throw an exception. And even if it would throw one, what would you do? Display it? Retry the operation?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, it is not an infinite loop. The loop just has its exit condition inside the body:

```
return current;
```

In general, this is the typical idiom used in optimistic, lock-free atomic operations. A Compare-And-Swap (CAS) operation is retried until it succeeeds, and it will succeed as soon as it is not contended from another thread. More precisely, the exit condition is met whenever the return value of `get()` matches the current value as observed by `compareAndSet()`. It is very hard *not* to meet this condition, and it happens very rarely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.If somehow compareAndSet does not written true and prev and newValue(because its a counter or something whose value does not repeat) will never matched. Is there a specific reason for using for loop? should not there be some exception raised or other exiting strategy?

Comment: No, retrying is exactly the expected strategy for all lock-free atomic operations.